# Search through articles C#

Tags: c#, search, optimization

I need to implement a list of articles with a search bar, and I want it to be an AutoComplete search, testing if all any word of the article starts with what's in the search field.

I was thinking of doing a list of word and article id in which every word appear, and then an array of that list, ordered alphabetically ([0] starts with a, [1] with b, etc...) I was also thinking of doing it by orderer dictyonaries, but I don't know if it's a better method.

I tried to find a book or something that talks about optimization in searching, but I couldn't find anything.

Is this a good method? If not, what method should I use or can you recommend me a book where I can learn it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't know if I can recommend doing this. Unfortunately doing this well is not  one man job. If you are interested in search engines you can have a look at [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) its open source so you can have a look at it. And if you want something grate out of the box have a look at [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch?elektra=home&storm=sub1).

Comment: Otherwise, please include at least parts of the data model in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: scan the articles and for every word generate the list of prefixes and add them to a dictionary (hash table), with links to the parent words.

Option 2: use a trie.